# How JAXB handle interfaces for marshall + jersey

Tags: spring, jaxb, jersey

Am trying to marshall a class that contains a List of Interface type. JAXB complains that he cannot handle interfaces.

```
  class Myclass{

        private List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
        .... 

  }
  interface MyInterface{
          get();
  }
```

How can i annotate this so that jaxb can marshall an instance of MyClass class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlElement` annotation to provide the JAXB implementation with the concrete class that you want to use for that interface.

```
class MyClass{

    @XmlElement(type=MyInterfaceImpl.class)
    private List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
    .... 

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html